# Angular Lifecycle hook when there is a change on service

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have a service - let´s call ServiceA,

which makes multiple HTTP calls and I want to retrieve info when everything is calculated.For that I have a boolean variable - isEverythingProcessed, when that happens.

On my component - let´s call ComponentB,

I´m doing:

```
ngOnCheck(){
    
    if(this.serviceA.isEverythingProcessed){
    
    //dostuff
    
    }
}
```

this works, but it´s called hundred of times.There is any alternative for this, I mean to have a lifecycle that is implemented on component detecting when a variable of the service is being changed?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an observable of the the soon-to-be-updated value onInit using rxjs, and subscribe to changes. This is how I've seen it done. Although, if something works and there's not a serious performance hit (an optimized fn call with a single if statement even if its called a few hundred times isn't really that bad although not ideal) I wouldn't overengineer it.

Comment: I highly recommend you to study  BehaviourSubject.

Answer (score 1):

A `Subject` would probably suffice here, as your component is listening for the change. For example a BehaviorSubject would always emit when there is a listener, but you probably just want to listen when it emits, exactly when it emits. So create a Subject in the service instead of a boolean variable, subscribe to that in the component and do your magic when the subject emits. Remember to unsubscribe when component is destroyed!

So I suggest the following

Service:

```ts
isEverythingProcessed = new Subject<boolean>();
```

and when all your calculations are done, call `next()` on it:

```ts
this.isEverythingProcessed.next(true)
```

And component:

```ts
this.service.isEverythingProcessed.subscribe((bool: boolean) => {
  // do stuff!
})
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-npntq6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

If you need an initial value and always trigger, I suggest a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`.